# Defining global variables for a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, project-structure, project-structuring

Suppose I have coded a particular Python package. What is the proper way to structure global variables? Should I define all global variables in one file and simply import them everywhere else? Is there a proper way to define global variables for a python package?

Answer (score 2):

> **How do I share global variables across modules?** The canonical way to
> share information across modules within a single program is to create
> a special module (often called config or cfg). Just import the config
> module in all modules of your application; the module then becomes
> available as a global name. Because there is only one instance of each
> module, any changes made to the module object get reflected
> everywhere.

For example:

config.py:

```
x = 0   # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting
```

mod.py:

```
import config
config.x = 1
```

main.py:

```
import config
import mod
print(config.x)
```

> Note that using a module is also the basis for implementing the
> Singleton design pattern, for the same reason.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)